# Nodes removal from a layered graph

Tags: graph-theory, upper-lower-bounds

Given a directed layered graph $G=(V,E)$, which its nodes are arranged in $n+1$ layers $L_1,...L_{n+1}$, s.t. the first and last layers have a single source and target nodes respectively ($L_1={s}, L_{n+1}={t}$). Edges are directed and only between adjacent layers, so if $e=(u,v) \in E$  then $u \in L_i$ and $v \in L_{i+1}$.

Consider the following process: We remove nodes one-by-one from the graph. If as a result of a removal, there is a different node that is no longer reachable from $s$ or that $t$ is not reachable from it, then we remove it too and so on.

The question is--what is the largest number of removal that can be applied (not including nodes that has been removed as a result of another node's removal), without disconnecting $s$ from $t$?

Is it possible to give an upper-bound for this number, depending on the number of nodes/edges/layers in the graph? (considering the worst-case order of nodes removal)

Answer (score 1):

You may want to look at [Menger's Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Menger%27s_theorem).
This tells us that the number of nodes you can remove between $s$ and $t$ without disconnecting them is equal to the number of internally disjoint paths from $s$ to $t$ (there are directed and undirected versions of this).

Since deleting a whole layer always disconnects $s$ and $t$, there is a trivial lower bound is $\min\{|L_i|: 2\leq i \leq n\}$.

It's also easy to show that you can construct a graph with $m$ nodes, in which the smallest $s-t$ separating set has $m-2$ nodes (i.e., the whole rest of the graph, see the figure).
[image]

EDIT: It is possible to find a bound based on the order of the graph, and the number of layers. If the graph has $m$ vertices, and $n+1$ layers, then $m-2$ of the vertices (everything except $s$ and $t$) lie in the middle $n-1$ layers. Thus, by the pigeonhole principle, there is some layer $L_i$ that has at most $\lfloor \frac{m-2}{n-1} \rfloor$ vertices. Removing this whole layer disconnects $s$ and $t$, so the number of removals you can make is bounded above by $\lfloor \frac{m-2}{n-1} \rfloor$.

Comment: Can you please explain how does the rest of the graph you drew is constructed?
Also, note that what I'm looking for is not exactly the larger set of nodes which disconnect the graph, but a set of nodes removal actions. Each action can followed by a removal of additional nodes, bu I don't want to count them in the calculation.

Comment: The rest of the graph is just more nodes between $s$ and $t$, all in one layer. Also, if you can remove a set of nodes $v_1, v_2, \dots, v_k$ without separating $s$ and $t$, then you can also make $k$ 'removal actions' without separating $s$ and $t$, so the questions are, in this case, the same. If an 'extra' vertex $w$ gets deleted by a removal action when you remove $v$, then $w$ was not on any $s-t$ path in $G-v$ anyway, so the extra vertices deleted in the removal don't change anything.

Comment: Ok I understood now that in your example there is only 1 layer.
This of course a boundary case in which the entire graph would need to be removed.
Is it possible to produce a bound which depends also on the number of layers? so it would be relevant

Comment: @OfirGordon Yes, I have edited to include a bound based on the number of nodes and number of layers.